# PHP words array count

Tags: php, arrays

My array is

> $myarray=array("Human","Angel",God"","Angel","Devil","God","God","Human","God","Angel");

How to get the word and count like

```
God : 4
Angel : 3
Human : 2
Devil : 1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This is a "read the documentation" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [arsort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php).

```
<?php  
$myarray = array("Human","Angel","God","Angel","Devil","God","God","Human","God","Angel");

$result = array_count_values($myarray);
arsort($result);

foreach($result as $word => $count)
{
    echo $word." was found ".$count." time(s)<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

See [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php).

From the documentation:

```
Example #1 array_count_values() example
<?php
  $array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
  print_r(array_count_values($array));
?> 

Array
(
  [1] => 2
  [hello] => 2
  [world] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [array-count-values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) function.