# Count number of occurences of words from one array in another array

Tags: php

I have two arrays: `$story` and `$languages`

Now I want to know how many times elements or values in `$languages` appear in `$story` array. This means how many times "php", "javascript", "mysql" of `$languages` array appeared in `$story`?

How can I do this in php? Can anyone help? Here are my arrays...

```
$story = array();
$story[] = 'As a developer, I want to refactor the PHP & javascript so that it has less duplication';
$story[] = ' As a developer, I want to configure Jenkins so that we have continuous integration and I love mysql';
$story[] = ' As a tester, I want the test cases defined so I can test the system using php language and phpunit framework';

$languages = array(
  'php', 'javascript', 'mysql'  
);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14610086/php-words-array-count

Answer (score 2):

I would store the totals in your `$languages` array. No need to check the count before adding, because adding 0 won't affect your totals.

```
<?
    $story = array();
    $story[] = 'As a developer, I want to refactor the PHP & javascript so that it has less duplication';
    $story[] = ' As a developer, I want to configure Jenkins so that we have continuous integration and I love mysql';
    $story[] = ' As a tester, I want the test cases defined so I can test the system using php language and phpunit framework';

    $languages = array(
        'php' => 0,
        'javascript' => 0,
        'mysql' => 0
    );

    foreach ($story as $sk => $sv){
        foreach ($languages as $lk => $lv){
            $languages[$lk] += substr_count($story[$sk], $lk);
        }
    }

    print_r($languages);
?>
```

Comment: Good answer. If word boundaries or caseless matching is needed, could replace the `substr_count` part with `$languages[$lk] += preg_match_all('/\b'.preg_quote($lk, "/").'\b/i', $story[$sk]);`

Comment: Hm, but not overlaps, will the regex fix that? I _really_ want to believe the OP won't have any overlaps. Please, please no whammies....

Comment: Overlapping was not mentioned by OP also not caseless matching or boundaries, just wanted to mention as a supplement :]

Comment: Yeah, I would expect any reasonable "Story" to have mixed case and boundary issues. Overlaps would mean the story was terrible in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

With 2 loops:
https://ideone.com/grRBeG

```
$story = array();
$story[] = 'As a developer, I want to refactor the PHP & javascript so that it has less duplication';
$story[] = ' As a developer, I want to configure Jenkins so that we have continuous integration and I love mysql';
$story[] = ' As a tester, I want the test cases defined so I can test the system using php language and phpunit framework';

$languages = [
    'php' => 0,
    'javascript' => 0,
    'mysql' => 0,
];

for( $i=0,$size=count($story); $i<$size; ++$i )
{
    $text = strtolower($story[$i]);
    foreach( $languages as $word => $nb )
        $languages[$word] += substr_count($text, $word);
}

var_export($languages);
```

Comment: Since this is mostly a copy of my answer, I should reiterate what the comments have said, `substr_count` takes care of case matching. So that you know, running `strtolower` in this case only adds processing and serves no purpose.

Comment: I won't down vote you or anything, not worth it, keep your 10pts, but others coming to this page should know to avoid this answer, regardless of how tacky it is.

Answer (score 0):

Run two `foreach` loops as shown below.

```
$finalCount = array();
foreach($story as $current)
{
      $count=0;
     foreach($languages as $language){
         if (substr_count($current,$language) !== false) {
           $count++
         }
     }
     $finalCount[$language] = $count;

}
```